# Writing to an Excel template using .NET with DocumentFormat.OpenXml, GUIDs are parsed as numbers and truncated if they begin with a numeral

Tags: c#, .net, excel, openxml, openxml-sdk

I'm using DocumentFormat.OpenXml in .NET Framework 4.5 (legacy app) to populate an Excel template and in one of the columns I'm writing GUIDs.

If a GUID's first character is a letter (say, `a9a14494-bc2b-4e44-bfb4-e35189aec84d`), everything works just fine.
However, if a GUID begins with a numeral, it will be truncated at the first occurrence of a letter. For example, `4705f1e0-8f5d-489f-a932-5c8d63281e21` will show up as `4705`.

The code I'm using to populate the cells is very simple:

```
// cell is a variable of type DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.Cell
// guidString is a string containing a GUID
cell.CellValue = new CellValue(guidString);
```

I have tried formatting the column in question as text, in the template, with no visible changes.
I've added a space before the GUID and the output is the same.
I've added a quote (`'`) before the GUID and the GUIDs are written in full; however, the quote is also written to the Excel file (e.g. `'4705f1e0-8f5d-489f-a932-5c8d63281e21`), which I don't want.

Any help in getting all GUIDs to be written in full would be appreciated.

Comment: You're setting the cell value, not the cell's text. You didn't post any code that specifies what the cell's style is either, so Excel has to guess that. Why are you using the low level OpenXML SDk instead of eg Epplus or ClosedXML?

Comment: As for `.NET Framework 4.5`, that version went out of support in 2016. Your application already runs on a newer runtime because all supported Windows installations come with a newer version. The oldest supported .NET Framework version right now is .NET Framework 4.6.2

Comment: If you check the [CellValue documentation examples](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/documentformat.openxml.spreadsheet.cellvalue?view=openxml-2.8.1) you'll see that `cel.DataType = CellValues.String` is used to specify that a cell contains text. If you store `cell.CellValue` only you're forcing Excel to guess what the contents are

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The snippet doesn't specify the cell's data type so Excel has to guess what the contents of `CellValue` are.

In the [CellValue documentation examples](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/documentformat.openxml.spreadsheet.cellvalue?view=openxml-2.8.1), `cel.DataType = CellValues.String` is used to specify that a cell contains text.

```
Row row = new Row() { RowIndex = 2U, Spans = new ListValue<StringValue>() };  
Cell cell = new Cell()  
{  
    CellReference = "A2",  
    DataType = CellValues.String,  
    CellValue = new CellValue("Microsoft")  
};  

row.Append(cell);  
sheetData.Append(row);
```

It's a lot easier to use a higher level library like EPPlus or ClosedXML instead of the low-level OpenXML SDK. With both EPPlus or ClosedXML filling a sheet with data can be done in as little as one line :

```
sheet.Cells.LoadFromCollection(customers c => c.PrintHeaders = true);
```

As for .NET Framework 4.5, that version went out of support in 2016. Your application already runs on a newer runtime because all supported Windows installations come with a newer version. The oldest supported .NET Framework version right now is .NET Framework 4.6.2

Comment: Thank you! Setting the cell value to string solved my issue. I thought doing that in the template itself would have the same effect.

Comment: I've never used DocumentFormat.OpenXml before (or, in fact, written to Excel programatically). I didn't really get to decide the approach or the technology, this is a legacy app and my task is to add a column with GUIDs. The rest of the table is being populated in the same (or in a similar) way, without any issue.

Comment: If you haven't used the OpenXML SDK, use one of the other libraries. The OpenXML SDK is very low level, almost at the level of XML elements. You have to do everything yourself. `LoadFromCollection` or `LoadFromTable` on the other hand will use the property or column types and names to generate cells with the correct types and styles, include headers and even apply one of the predefined table styles.